# Probability that $k$ balls are white and black if $2k$ balls are selected from an urn

Tags: probability

> Say we have an urn consisting of $m+n$ balls, with $m$ being black, $n$ being white and $m>n$. We now select $2k$ balls from the urn. What is the probability that $k$ of them are white and $k$ of them are black? (The balls are chosen without replacement.)

There are two ways to solve this problem, the boring way and the interesting way. The boring way is the following brute-force calculation:

---

The probability that the balls are drawn in the order of any given permutation of white/black  balls consisting of $k$ white and $k$ black balls is the same, and indeed equal to

$$\mathbb{P}(\text{permutation})=\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\dots(m-k)n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k)}{(m+n)(m+n-1)\dots(m+n-2k)}$$

Since the number of such permutations is $\frac{2k!}{k!k!}$, it follows that the probability required by the question is

$$\frac{2k!}{k!k!}\mathbb{P}(\text{permutation})$$

---

There is also an *interesting* way to solve this problem, which involves elegently selecting combinations and intuitively placing them on either side of the fraction.

What is the interesting way to solve this problem?

Comment: When you choose the $2k$ balls, is it with or without replacement?  Without specifying this, there is no way to answer.  You have been here long enough to know that.   It looks like you are drawing without replacement, but you should say so.  -1 and vote to close.  What makes you think there is an interesting way?

Comment: @RossMillikan It was an oversight, I have edited the question. The reason I know there is an interesting way is because I was docked points in a test and was given the reason that there is a better way to solve this which involves using combinations.

Comment: You have not really solved the problem because the probability of a permutation depends on the fact that the first $2k$ balls are evenly distributed rather than random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the hypergeometric distribution approach:
$$\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{m+n}{2k}}$$

Comment: In case both of our answers are wrong, do the answers *become* right if everybody agrees?

Comment: We're both right, and I gave you a +1. :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{m+n}{2k}}.$$

The numerator represents the number of different ways of selecting $k$ balls out of $n$ and $k$ balls out of $m$.  The denominator is the number of ways of selecting $(2k)$ balls from $(m+n)$ balls.